# What is the use of BOOST converter in this circuit?

Tags: boost, supercapacitor

Here is a circuit in which a supercapacitor is in parallel with the battery to manage the high pulse current requirement without stressing the battery. What is the use of boost converters here?

One more doubt-->

Are these boost converters are required if i am using 3.6v battery and I only need a 3.4v-3.6v Vout? I am using 5.5V, 4.7F cap.

[image]

Comment: 1) to generate 4.1V. 2) Not necessarily. Calculate the Q you get from discharging from 3.6 to 3.4V and compare that with your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the only way to get 4.1V from a 3.5V supply, it also handles the voltage droop shown as "Vin"

if your voltage needs are less critical you may not need the boost regulator.